# On the 4Clojure website, how do you see your previous problems, so you can return to one of them?

Tags: clojure

I'm doing problems at 4Clojure.  Some how, when I finished a problem (around #22), a link appeared that jumped me to problem #35.  I want to do the problems that were skipped.  But when I'm logged in to 4Clojure, the website only shows me problems after the last one I completed, which is #34.

Is there way to see all the problems (completed and uncompleted) at 4Clojure, so I can do the skipped ones?

Comment: Are you sure this is an appropriate question to StackOverflow? Should be moved to SuperUser instead... maybe... not sure...

Comment: @Dadinn I agree it's a bit close, but I think it can plausibly qualify under "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers on the problem list page are all clickable to change sort order. The default sort order is something like "sort first on whether you've solved it, and then on how many other people have solved it", so problems you've solved drift to the bottom (which is on page 2). You can click a heading to sort differently: for example, click on the Solved heading to see the problems you've already solved first.

Or, of course, you can just edit the URL, since the URLs are very predictable: http://www.4clojure.com/problem/22 will be problem #22.

Comment: Thanks.  I can get a lot more from 4Clojure with this info.

Answer (score 1):

Change the number in the URL:
http://www.4clojure.com/problem/[problem]

Your completed problems appear at the very end of the problem list.

Comment: This isn't the question I asked, but I would've asked it soon.  Thanks for telling how see already answered questions.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a list of all the problems:
[Problem List](http://www.4clojure.com/problems)

However they are not numbered.